# using "like" with cell to reference the last four digits in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-query

[hardCode formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOZbP.png)
[dynamic formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MQ8X.png)
I am using google sheets to make a report related to customers projects,

in my company When we have new project we give the project a 4 digits number then we create account receivable for the customer contain of 14 digits like that : 
the first 6 digits is fixed
the second 4 digits represent the year and month
the last 4 digits represent the project number

so i have column with the Project number and i want to make a query that return the count of costumer payment in front of the project number , when i try to use this formula :

> =QUERY({'2016DB'!$A$2:$H$18168;'2018DB'!$A$2:$H$13379;'2017DB'!$A$2:$H$17759;'2019DB'!$A$2:$H},"select
>   count(Col3) where Col1 = 12040118091492 And Col3 > 0 label count(Col3)
>   '' ",0)

it's work fine

But when i try to make it dynamic by using like statement :

> QUERY({'2016DB'!$A$2:$H$18168;'2018DB'!$A$2:$H$13379;'2017DB'!$A$2:$H$17759;'2019DB'!$A$2:$H},"select
>   count(Col3) where Col1 like 120401____"""&E7&""" And Col3 > 0 label
>   count(Col3) '' ",0)

Where E7 Cell Contain the Project number it doesn't work  !!

Comment: Could you make a screenshot of what you currently have and what you need t achieve?

Comment: i edited the question to add the screenshot @ILyaCyclone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a simple example with your type of query. Check this, please: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ISG0AjMNhwnXQvlxDJCMHcyx8mDKiCv6zqOfAGxrrDg/edit?usp=sharing (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOBuH.png)

Main formula is: `=QUERY(A1:A5, "select A where A like 'a__"&D1&"'")` where D1 is your needed project number. Looked up values are in format: letter `a` followed by 2 any characters and then project number.

Mind double and single quotes.

[image]

Comment: it doesn't work for me, i think because in my case the data between single quotes is numbers only and not contain any letter like yours @ILya Cyclone

Comment: Made the same thing on second sheet with numbers only.  Formula: `=QUERY(A1:A6, "select A where A like '1__"&D1&"'")` Screen: https://i.imgur.com/7xID2Zk.png

Comment: Also this part or your formula look scary: `where Col1 like 120401____"""&E7&""" And`. You could try `where Col1 like '120401____"&E7&"' And` instead.